# Change locale in rails outside session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, rails-i18n

I am learning Rails and I want to setup localisation for my app. I can do it without any issue for each user (i.e. each user can select their language and the app changes to the selected language) but I want to add the option to change language even before login so everyone can understand how the app works or what does it offers, contact and about pages and so on.

I have added a dropdown menu with the list of languages and the each button will call an action on my "staticpages" controller. Here is how the dropdown looks like:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<% get_languages_list.each do |lan| %>
    <li> <%= link_to lan[0], {controller: "static_pages", action: "change_locale", locale: lan[1]}, method: "post" %></li>
<%end%>
</ul>
```

where get_languages_list is a helper that returns and array of arrays with the languages my app support with a human name, for example [["English","en"],["Español"],["es"],...]. The action that it calls is this one:

```
def change_locale
    if params.include? :locale 
        I18n.default_locale = lan locale
    end
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

I thought that with this it would be enough but it seems that I18n doesn't remember what the locale is. With my user model, in order to change the locale what I do is a before_action filter and set the locale to the locale of the user but in this case, when I don't have any session opened how can I change the locale to the specific one selected by the user?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: None, it just doesn't change the locale, it stays as before.

Comment: Does it actually hit the `change_locale` method? You can test this if you add `byebug` in your method.

Comment: Yes, it calls the method since I introduced a bug there before and got triggered, the redirect_to also works. It is like after the redirect_to the locale goes back to normal.